# How to install OGRE SDK in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ogre, installation

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 in VMware. Now I want to install OGRE and Eclipse but I don't know which version of OGRE SDK I should install. [The OGRE SDK download page](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/sdk) has many links, but none that says it is for Ubuntu. Which one should I get?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=CMake%20Quick%20Start%20Guide&tikiversion=Linux). The [source code download page](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/source) is currently pointing at [OGRE 1.8.1 Source for Linux / OSX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/ogre/1.8/1.8.1/ogre_src_v1-8-1.tar.bz2/download). Don't forget to read through the [Prerequisites](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Prerequisites?tikiversion=Linux)!